# NewLine Character for sending sms in code behind in C#.net

Tags: c#

The sms message comes as a single string, I want to break the text into different lines but no newline character seems to do the trick.

sdr.Read();

```
                        PrisonerStatus = sdr.GetString(0);
                        LastName = sdr.GetString(1);
                        MiddleName = sdr.GetString(2);
                        FirstName = sdr.GetString(3);
                        Gender = sdr.GetString(4);
                        DateOfBirth = sdr.GetString(5);
                        Genotype = sdr.GetString(6);
                        BloodGroup = sdr.GetString(7);
                        DateOfCommittal = sdr.GetString(8);
                        DateOfNaturalExpirationOfSentence = sdr.GetString(9);
                        ActualDateOfRelease = sdr.GetString(10);
                        CellInfo = sdr.GetString(11);
                        Color = sdr.GetString(12);
                        TribeOrCountryOfOrigin = sdr.GetString(13);


                        sdr.Close();

                        if (tokens[2] == "details")
                        {
                            //This is where i need the formating so sms receiver sees it as shown below
                            //PS. Using Ozeki Message server
                            message = "PrisonerID : " + prisonID + '\n' +
                                      "Full Name : " + LastName + " " + MiddleName + " " + FirstName + '\n' +
                                      "Gender : " + Gender;

                            SendToOutbox(message);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            message = "Unknown transaction code";
                            output.UpdateDisplay("Error :" + message);
                            SendToOutbox(message);
                            goto Label_021C;
                        }
```

Comment: Did you try `\r\n` instead of just `\n`?

Comment: You can use `Environment.NewLine` which is `\r\n` on Windows.

Comment: That's some scary code... New line character depends on API you are using. You need to consult it's documentation or author. Try some common ones. "\n", "\r\n", in lack of better ideas "&#10;", "%0A", "<br>"...

Comment: [this](http://www.twilio.com/help/faq/sms/how-do-i-add-a-line-break-in-my-sms-message) might help.

Comment: Is it possible that this code needs to be run inside of a `chroot` jail?

Comment: try \0x0A, this will work

Comment: Doesn't work. Am using ozeki message server engine. A gprs modem is serving as d link between my .net code and the end user - that will send a transac code to my code to display a prisoner info.

Answer (score 8):

This should work, use the `"` instead of `'`

```
message = "PrisonerID : " + prisonID + "\n" +
          "Full Name : " + LastName + " " + MiddleName + " " + FirstName + "\n" +
          "Gender : " + Gender;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this code:

Notice the : **@"\0x0A"**

```
message = "PrisonerID : " + prisonID + @"\0x0A" +
"Full Name : " + LastName + " " + MiddleName + " " + FirstName + @"\0x0A" +
"Gender : " + Gender;
```

Answer (score 1):

I have used the `<br>` tag sending the sms using C# and using PHP and it has worked for me
Example :

```
message = "PrisonerID : " + prisonID + "<br>" +
"Full Name : " + LastName + " " + MiddleName + " " + FirstName + "<br>" +
"Gender : " + Gender;
```